# Series power with unusual denominator

Tags: series-expansion

I have a series whose terms are:
(x^n)/(n+a)
where n is a positive integer, x a real number that is greater than 0 and smaller than 1, and a is a real number smaller than 1. It is easy to proof that the series converges, but I cannot find if it is the series expansion of an algebraic function.
Can anybody help me?
Thank you in advance
Marco

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

```
Sum[(x^n)/(n + a), {n, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> True]
(* ConditionalExpression[HurwitzLerchPhi[x, 1, a], Abs[x] <= 1 && x != 1] *)
```